# How can I use my stock portfolio in order to get a lower interest rate mortgage?

Tags: mortgage, security-lending

#### Background

I have a decent amount of money saved up, most of it invested in the stock market. Right now I'm thinking about getting a condo / house. I have more than enough in my stock portfolio to simply buy a property in the price range I'm looking at outright, without requiring a mortgage. However, interest rates are so low right now that it makes sense to me to get a mortgage anyways. In addition, there's tax benefits etc.

I'm aware of the general concept of securities backed loans, but the general rates I see from large companies are horrendous (~7-9%). On the other hand, I know I can get ~2% margin loans from Interactive Brokers, though I've never actually used them myself and I'm unsure if I'll run into any complications there. I haven't been able to find a specialized financial instrument to accomplish what I'm looking for.

I feel like there should be a way where I can obtain a mortgage using both the property and part of my stock portfolio as combined collateral, and get a substantially reduced mortgage rate in return.

#### Question

Is there a way that I can use my stock portfolio to get a lower rate on my mortgage? Ideally, it should be under the margin rate from Interactive Brokers.

#### Additional Info

- Country: US
- State: Likely WA, FL, TX, or NV

Comment: A great question.  Saccharine, what are some examples of the "horrendous rates" you mention?

Comment: I don't think the market is going to increase so quickly that buying the property outright and reinvesting whatever you would have spent on a mortgage is not a valid option.

Comment: Getting a mortgage "for the tax benefit" makes no sense. You are getting a deduction to offset an expense you wouldn't have had in the first place.

Comment: Can you clarify: are you in the United States, Canada, or elsewhere?

Comment: Yes, to chepner's point, the tax benefit provides a discount on the loan rate, e.g. my 3.5% mortgage 'really' costs me 2.73%.  If that difference between gross and net are important, then one has budgeted too tightly.

Comment: @chepner: It does make sense. When the mortgage interest is tax deductible, the effective mortgage interest rate is lowered. When this effective rate becomes lower than the risk-free interest rate on savings, it is cheaper to buy a house with that mortgage than from your savings. Won't work in Europe at the moment, where the risk-free interest rate on savings is 0%. Probably never worked in the US, as the taxes are structurally too low to make the deduction worthwhile.

Comment: @MSalters Lower than 0%? If your *only* reason to take a mortgage is to have deduct the interest, you are paying more in interest than you are saving on your tax bill.

Comment: @chepner It's not about the tax benefit.  It's comparing gains from investments against loss on the mortgage interest.  There are plenty of stable stocks that offer dividends that are higher than mortgage interest rates.

Comment: Yes, but your expected loss in the early mortgage payments is much, much higher than the rate. You have a 3% interest rate, but well over 50% of each payment is lost to interest when you could have been reinvesting it in the stocks you sold to buy the house outright. A mortgage might still make sense, but it's more complicated than simply comparing annual growth rates to mortgage interest rates.

Comment: @chepner: It doesn't matter how much of the payment is interest. The math doesn't work like that. If 50% of the payment going to interest bothers you, you can voluntarily pay extra principal, but it won't make the loan a better deal. The interest payments aren't money you could have been reinvesting if you didn't take the loan - they're money you *wouldn't have had* if you didn't take the loan. They're a cut of your profit, as long as (after adjusting for tax) your investments return more than the loan's interest rate.

Comment: @Fattie I updated the answer but large companies like JP Morgan have 7-9%. It's so astoundingly high considering there's collateral being provided I'm actually curious who signs up for it.

Comment: @C8H10N4O2 US. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For perspective the rates you are seeing are not horrendous.  It was not that long ago when people were happy to get a 8% mortgage because their parents percentage rates were in the teens.

I think you have two options with a third if you already owned a home.

The first, is the one you already know about the margin loan.  This is very popular among some people with money.  It would be best to use very stable stocks to secure the loan with a lot of wiggle room.  You don't want a margin call.

The second is using an institution with a brokerage.  For example if you use JP Morgan and Chase you can get perks for being a "private client".  One of those perks is a break on your mortgage rate.

The third is to use a home equity loan to finance a home.  If you put the loan in first position, get a fixed rate for a fixed term, the rates are very low.  Typically about a point lower than the prevailing 15 year rate.  Also the closing cost may be low or non-existent.  The drawback is you have to own a property first.  In your case you could buy the property from investments, then initiate the HEL, and then replenish your investments.

Editorially, even with these low rates there is no good reason to have a mortgage.  If you can buy a property for cash, then you should just do so.  Increasing your free cash flow is far more valuable IMHO.

Comment: "The third is to use a home equity loan to finance a home." Did you mean something else here?

Comment: @Acccumulation nope,  You can get a HEL to refi a home.  Putting it in first position greatly reduced the risk for the bank, and correspondingly the rate.

Comment: Do you mean take out a HEL and use the money to pay off the mortgage?

Comment: @Acccumulation no, that would be silly.  Why pay the cost of initiating a mortgage?  Buy the house for cash taken from investment accounts, then get the HEL, then replenish the investments.

Comment: "The Chase Mortgage Rate Program offers Chase Private Clients rate discounts of 0.125% for total deposits and investments in personal accounts of $250,000 – $999,999 or 0.25% for $1,000,000+"
Honestly the 0.125% - 0.25% probably doesn't even offset the increased costs of moving from Vanguard. Looks like margin is the only option I have.

Comment: Why would a HEL have a lower rate than a mortgage? I feel like they are essentially the same thing from the bank's POV. But, one difference that is possibly relevant here, is that a HEL is only tax deductible if the funds are used to upgrade the home. In this case the HEL would most likely not be tax deductible.

Answer (score 16):

I don't think adding stock as collateral will help you get a significantly better rate. The mortgage you'll get is *already* fully collateralized, since you won't be able to borrow more than the house is worth (and hopefully can put down enough down payment that the loan is over-collateralized to avoid PMI). If you default, the bank is most likely going to get their money back by foreclosing on the house - they won't *need* your extra collateral.

Since collateral is not an issue, then the basis for your rate is your credit worthiness. Do you have sufficient stable income to make the payments safely? Do you have any history of missed payments or overuse of credit? Those are the issues that will have a bigger effect on your mortgage rate.

If you want to reduce your mortgage rate, you could sell enough of your stock to get the loan-to-value well below 80%, significantly reducing the loss to the bank if you should default.

> I'm aware of the general concept of securities backed loans, but the general rates I see from large companies are horrendous.

That's probably because these are *desperation* loans by people that have bad credit, and the fact that the collateral could go down in value very easily.  Those facts increase the risk of loss, thereby requiring a higher interest rate to compensate for the risk.

Comment: If banks always get all of their money back from foreclosures, why would they care about credit worthiness? Why aren't mortgages risk free loans regardless of credit history of the borrower?

Comment: Well, I said "most likely", but that may be a bit of an overstatement. Certainly after the costs of foreclosure are taken into account there may be some loss. But the point is that adding additional collateral is not going to make the loan "risk free"

Comment: @DStanley And, I would be willing to bet that there is a pretty good correlation between those who default on their mortgage and those who don't do a great job of upkeep. So the bank may not be able to sell it for as much as the loan was worth either

Comment: Also look at it in terms of opportunity cost. The bank can give a loan to someone with bad credit who defaults and it takes them 5 years to foreclose, sell, and break even. The bank still loses when they break even, because they could have instead loaned that money to someone with better credit who would have paid them back with interest.

Comment: Securities-backed loans aren't desperation loans. Desperation loans are stuff like payday loans and credit card debt. Stuff with double-digit or higher interest rates. Securities-backed loans are for people who *have* assets and just have some reason to prefer a loan over selling them - maybe tax reasons, maybe the assets are illiquid or something.

Comment: @DStanley  Outside of opportunity cost, the rate should be based off the prime rate as well as the overall risk of the loan. Surely by adding additional collateral I am significantly decreasing the risk of the loan to where it's almost zero? The overall mortgage should then be risk free to the bank. I also tried on bankrate setting a mortgage with 40% down but the best rates only went from 2.64 to 2.6. For larger financial institutions it didn't even go down at all.

Comment: @saccharine Again, because the loan is almost fully collateralized by the house. Adding _more_ collateral does not offer the bank any more protection. Even if they _can_ get their money back, there's still costs associated with foreclosure that they would need to go through (and they want to make a profit), hence the additional spread over risk-free rates.

Comment: @DStanley any additional foreclosure costs would be more than offset by the increased collateral. There is no way I could believe that banks wouldn't just add the cost of foreclosure to the loan itself.

Answer (score 2):

As the other answers have basically said, "No, because your borrowing rate is determined by your collateral". For a home loan you are paying one of the lowest rates because of the nature of that collateral being fairly secure from a historical perspective.

In addition, with a home loan you can get a fixed rate pretty close to 2%.  With a margin loan you are effectively paying a *variable* rate which is determined most likely by some formula based on the prime rate plus some margin, or perhaps some proprietary formula that is not published.  I doubt that IB will mind you borrowing for 15 or 30 years as long as your collateral (portfolio) maintains its value, but your interest rate most assuredly will *not* be fixed at 2% for that whole time.

Comment: The lowest I can find on bankrate is ~ 2.6% and those are honestly companies I've never heard of. BoA is at 2.8. For reference, latest IB is at 1.1 % for <1M margin rates. Sure it's not fixed, but the difference is still significant.

Comment: @saccharine I got an offer for 1.999% a few weeks back (APY was substantially higher for some reason, 2.5%ish).  It didn't advertise any points or such but I didn't pursue it to see the fine print.